# Website is alerted with firefox as damaging/infected. Remove site from 'blacklist'

Tags: seo, security, spam, malware

My website is alerted as malicious/infected by firefox, so users can't have normal experience atm.

All threats are removed and website is clean. *How I can remove my website from this 'blacklist'?* *Might be some application for re-check or whatever?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [Firefox's page about attack sites and malware](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/phishing-protection/).

> Malware is software designed to infect your computer without your knowledge. Malware is most often used to steal personal information, send junk e-mail (spam), or spread more malware.
>
> Attack Sites are Web sites that try to infect your computer with malware when you visit. These attacks can be very difficult to detect; even a site that looks safe may be secretly trying to attack you. Sometimes the Web site’s owner won’t even know that the site has been turned into an Attack Site.
>
> You can learn more about malware and Attack Sites from [StopBadware](https://www.stopbadware.org/firefox), a non-profit organization that works with partners like Mozilla to protect users from malware and other dangerous software.

From [StopBadware](https://www.stopbadware.org/firefox), there is a way to ask them to remove your site from the list after you have removed the malware.

> Help! This is my site.
>
> We know this is frustrating. To remove the warnings, you'll need to find the problem, clean it up, and request a review. We can help you do this.
>
> [Get Started](https://www.stopbadware.org/my-site-has-badware)

StopBadware uses blacklists from various sources.  After you have removed the malware/hack from your site, you will have to use their [Clearinghouse Search](https://www.stopbadware.org/clearinghouse/search) function to figure out which blacklist you are on. Then you will have to request a review from that blacklist organization.

- [Instructions for requesting a review from Google](https://www.stopbadware.org/blacklisted-by-google)
- [Instructions for requesting a review from other organizations](https://www.stopbadware.org/blacklisted-by-others)

Comment: The problem is that i am not in Clearinghouse Search reports %) Very strange

Comment: I believe that most of StopBadware's blacklist actually comes from Google.  I would suggest looking in [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) and trying to solve the problem there first.

Comment: Yup! You are right!

Comment: Currently I don't have such option as to Request a review in my webmaster tooling. Any thoughts?

Comment: The use the link for Google on StopBadware: https://www.stopbadware.org/blacklisted-by-google